# Invalid delete[] array of pointer

Tags: c++

I am learning to create array of pointer and free up memory. This is my simple code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int* classroom[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    classroom[i] = new int;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    classroom[i] = &i;
    cout<<*classroom[i]<<endl;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    delete classroom[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run in valgrind to check for the memory leak, this is the result

```
==2868== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2868== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2868== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2868== Command: ./m
==2868== 
0
1
2
3
4
==2868== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2868==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2868==    by 0x8048700: main (in /home/student/Downloads/demo/m)
==2868==  Address 0xbea69244 is on thread 1's stack
==2868== 
==2868== 
==2868== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2868==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 5 blocks
==2868==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 20 bytes allocated
==2868== 
==2868== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2868==    definitely lost: 20 bytes in 5 blocks
==2868==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2868==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2868==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2868==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2868== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2868== 
==2868== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2868== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

My question is, why I have received the message "invalid free()/delete/delete[]/realloc[]" ? and how to fix it ?

Thanks,

Comment: U need to use delete []

Comment: @Gilad: nope. he hasn't allocated an array.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do in the second loop, consequently we cannot "fix" it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    classroom[i] = &i;
    cout<<*classroom[i]<<endl;
}
```

You are trashing the memory of the array.  You set all of the pointers to the address of `i` and then when the for loop ends `i` is destroyed and you now have dangling pointers.  attempting to delete them is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense to me now

Answer (score 0):

```
classroom[i] = &i;
```

should be:

```
*classroom[i] = i;
```

You're replacing the pointer that you allocated with `new` with the address of the local variable `i`. Then you later try to delete that pointer, but you can't delete local variables, only variables allocated with `new`. What you actually want to do is copy the value of `i` into the dynamically allocated variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that by the time you `delete` each `classroom` it no longer points to the original memory location of the `int` created by `new` because you are not pushing the value of `i` into the memory location of `classroom[i]`, you are actually changing `classroom[i]` to point to `i`'s memory location.

Try changing

```
classroom[i] = &i;
```

to

```
*(classroom[i]) = i;
```

Comment: Barmar beat me to it :)